# Currency converter applied to range via combobox

Tags: excel, converters, currency, vba

Is there a way to apply vba code to convert the currency of a range of cells without changing the formula within the cell based upon the type of currency chosen in a drop-down box.

So for instance:

1.) drop-down box(Hong Kong, London, Berlin)

2.) You choose (Hong Kong)

3.) sheet1.range("A5:A7") and sheet1.range("G5:G7") and sheet10.range("B5:B6") all change to the currency of the chosen location (i.e. HKD)

4.) You choose (Berlin) and all of the cells then adjust to Euros.

Is this type of vba even possible? How should I go about trying to code it.

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot do this without altering the formulas within the cells.  You could simply add a factor to all your formulas.  When this factor = 1 then the currency is USD (as an example), then it is updated (higher or lower) when you change currency in your combobox.

Answer (score 0):

1- Use data validation to create drop down lists in your code

2- Use the following event handler to check if the value of a cell has changed

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = Range("A1").Address Then
        'your code
    End If 
End Sub
```

where A1 is the cell with the drop down list

3- Use the macro recorder to figure out what code to add to apply to format change.